# Spotify SDK iOS SDK 403 error

Tags: ios, networking, sdk, spotify, http-status-code-403

New to iOS and programming in general. I'm working with Spotify SDK (beta) to try and make a client to stream tracks that I've saved.

When calling their savedTracksForUserInSession method, which I was told to do by their developers, I keep getting a 403 error: Forbidden.  My session is good, so is another method that is used to play their tracks/album/artists...

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
-(void)fetchSavedTrack:(SPTSession*) session {

[SPTRequest savedTracksForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage* trackList) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"This block is being run");

    self.savedTracks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:trackList.items];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.savedTracks);
}];
}
```

SOLUTION: 
Had to add SPTAuthUserLibraryReadScope scope for authorization.  Thanks, Armin for pointing it out to me.

Comment: You're trying to save a track to the user's library, so my suspicion is that your application hasn't been given the [user-library-modify scope](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/).

Comment: actually, this is to fetch the already saved tracks not save to library

Comment: Ah, I misread it as "saveTracksForUserInSession". Carry on :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to add the proper ["Scope"](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) to be able to get access to read the user's saved tracks. You probably need the `user-library-read` scope.